# How can you determine if installed programs have dependencies with other installed programs

Tags: applications

**Is it possible to see dependencies of programs with other programs ?** I mean, program which *must* be installed for other programs to run.

*-- background of the question --*

I installed a program a couple of weeks ago which let me read comics on my Android.

This program required Adobe Air - which was installed alongside the comic viewer.

After a couple of days I decided to uninstall the comic viewer.

I now want to remove Adobe Air (since it is a big program) , but was wondering whether other installed programs might require this too.

Comment: I'm guessing Android doesn't enforce this any more than desktop OSes do -- i.e. it's up to the app to check for its dependency -- but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Matthew Read: Yes, that's what I am thinking too. But you never know, some sort of (hidden) setting might provide this information. I didn't found one but that doesn't mean it doesn't exists.

Comment: App dependency is located in an apps manifest file, though not sure if the system makes checks on these.

Answer (score 1):

Any program that needs Adobe Air will have a check in it's code when it first runs to see if adobe air is installed.

Therefore if you uninstall Adobe Air then open an app that needs it, it will notify you to download it.

So uninstalling adobe air is fine.